# Migrate existing Users to Azure AD b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have old users Authentication flow depend on AspnetIdentity and we are planning to move the authentication from our end to use B2C

What is the easiest way to do that

and update AD b2c with the existing users

Comment: Please refer to this article.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration

Comment: Is the link provided by @ChauncyZhou what you need?

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it to end the thread, thanks！

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration) provided by @Chauncy is correct. You can migrate users to Azure AD B2C according to the two migration methods provided in the document.

> Migrating from another identity provider to Azure Active Directory B2C
> (Azure AD B2C) might also require migrating existing user accounts.
> Two migration methods are discussed here, pre migration and seamless
> migration. With either approach, you're required to write an
> application or script that uses the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations) to create user
> accounts in Azure AD B2C.